# CSS Transform square into thinner rhombus

Tags: css, matrix, transform

How to create a rhombus:[image: rhombus] (as shown in red) by transforming a square using css? Only points B and C must move. Original size of square is 25px by 25px.

I'm trying to achieve this result and would later rotate it 45 degrees so that it would look like a diamond. I think this can be done using the transform:matrix();

P.S. I want to try as much as possible to not use explorercanvas, since I'm trying to minimize script tags in the html.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg)
```

Change the skew values to affect how skinny your diamond gets.  This will push out the other corners and you'll need to scale the whole object if maintaining the specific dimensions is a requirement.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R4ym/) with the transformation you described.
And some [further reading](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) on CSS transformations.

Comment: Thanks! Was hitting my head trying to figure out transform:matrix when skew can work very well!

Answer (score 4):

I know you already accepted an answer, but you can do it without using `transform`, which is often quirky to implement cross-browser (especially in IE). The downside to my technique is that there are a couple more elements in play.

Based off this: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rQCQ5/

Comment: This is a good alternative solution.  Truthfully unless there's a reason for using CSS transforms the best way to deploy this to a webpage is as a gif with whatever sprite or data-src attribute optimizations are warranted.

Comment: @RSG: I agree. I would give you +1 for your valid answer, but I've unfortunately ran out of votes!

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately can't use this as I have to add a drop down shadow.

Comment: @UrBestFriend: In that case, you're right - you can't use this.

Answer (score 3):

Using scaleX or scaleY may be a little simpler:

```
transform: scaleX(.5) rotate(45deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/greypants/t5Dt8/

Just have to remember that the order matters, and it's the opposite of what you think it would be.

Answer (score 2):

Ana Tudor [suggests](http://youtu.be/w9HeWBH_kvg?t=7m6s) to use `skewX` and `scaleY` to compensate to keep the dimensions the same. For further understanding about how `skew` works, check the linked video

```
.rhombus {
    transform: skewX(30deg) scaleY(.86); /* .86 = cos(30deg) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also my way of doing it, but yet again I don't think it's possible to get shadows on it properly.

```
 .rhombus{
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: relative;
margin: -60px 0 0 60px;
border-bottom: solid 360px #000  ;
border-left: solid 240px transparent;
border-right: solid 240px transparent;
z-index:2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vCQ3c/