# CSS: creating background with shapes?

Tags: css

I'm just wondering if it is possible to create a background like the image bellow entirely using CSS?

or is their any online tool that does that and gives us the CSS code?

I don't know what this affect called to be honest so I don't know what to call it.

This is the image:

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, CSS cannot do anything of the sort. I think fiddling around with JS and HTML canvas would be the best way to go.

Comment: I think you can use `canvas`  to make this shapes

Comment: Or just use Photoshop or Illustrator and use `background-image`

Comment: @JonathanLam of course CSS can do that!

Comment: By using some CSS3.

Comment: I don't get why this question gets so many down votes.

Comment: Use svg to create such a complex shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, adding to all the answers with JS and Canvas, I want to add that you might are able to do this in CSS. With a huge amount of effort of course.

Using Background-gradients, you could create as many overlaying pictures as you want.
See this example: 
http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#japanese-cube

Comment: nice.. I really like this solution...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can achieve this in CSS alone, but [here is an online tool](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify-generator/) that lets you save a SVG or PNG to be used in your website. If you want to modify the code you can check out the [repo on github](https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify-generator)

Comment: Although only links answers are considered off-topic, i'll upvote it because that's some cool online tool!!

Comment: Sorry @AlonEitan, didn't mean to post off-topic. Tried to link to the code behind the online tool for that reason :) Will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could fill a `div` with a number of other `divs` and then transform them by using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Then you could add your actual content on top of the "background" `div`.

A working example with explanation seems to be available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572786/css-transform-square-into-thinner-rhombus).

Then again, this would be highly impractical and e.g. making the background in an image editing software would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the exact picture is reproducible using CSS. But you can create a lot of graphic patterns **using CSS3 background gradients**.

A lot of examples can be found on Lea Verou's blog: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

**Example** if a complex CSS background gradient:

```css
.pattern {
  width: 40em;
  height: 15em;
  
  background-color:#556;
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
  linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
  linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
  linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
  linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a), 
  linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
  background-size:80px 140px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 40px 70px, 40px 70px, 0 0, 40px 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern"></div>
```

Comment: That's about the same as my answer

Comment: @Type-Style Yeah, didn't see your answer before posting…